# Silverlight ChildWindow - Update label with textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0

I have very simple code in C# to present MessageBox:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello Action!");
```

Now I need to do the following: to replace the MessageBox by a Silverlight ChildWindow element, Add a label, a button and a textbox and after that Pressing the button updates the label content with the textbox content.

How to do it?
I did not find some example on the Net.

My full code is this:

```
namespace DevTrainingSilverlight2
{
    public class HelloAction : W6Action
    {
        public override void Initialize(W6ActionConfigSection configuration, UIElement containingControl, UIElement associatedControl)
        {
            base.Initialize(configuration, containingControl, associatedControl);
        }

        public override void UpdateState(System.Collections.IList selectedObjectsInFocus)
        {
            base.UpdateState(selectedObjectsInFocus);
        }

        public override void Invoke(System.Collections.IList selectedObjectsInFocus)
        {
            base.Invoke(selectedObjectsInFocus);
            MessageBox.Show("Hello Action!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the Textbox and the Button to the childwindow in silverlight.

And you can pass the content as a parameter while opening and update it like below.

```
 ChildWindowControl childControl = new ChildWindowControl(content);
 childControl.Show();
```

and change the constructor of Childwindow as follows,

```
public ChildWindowControl(string name)
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   this.lblValue = name;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, in my previous code I didn't have any elements (text box, labels etc.) Does it mean I have to add them from some toolbox? Where are they located? I created new project as Silverligt->Silverlight Class Library is that correct? Because toolbox from there is empty as I can see

Comment: Not silverlight class library. you should create silverlight application

Comment: Sorry Sajeetharan can you take a look at my full code (I updated the question). You can see there that I have a class which must implement W6Action interface and I need to implement Invoke() method. So can you please explain me if I have Silverlight application do I have and Silverlight Class or if not where will I put this code for Invoke() method which must be implemented. Sorry for extending what I actually need. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Dejan you can put the same code in an silverlight appliation. there wont be any issue

Comment: if you can give a team viwer i would help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100274/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-dejan).